# Semester units versus credit hours

Tags: graduate-admissions

This [graduate policy handbook](http://grad.berkeley.edu/policies/guides/f1-4-transfers-of-unit-credit-toward-the-master%E2%80%99s-degree/) states

> "A master’s student may transfer up to 4 semester units or 6 quarter
>   units of course work completed as a graduate student at another
>   institution."

In this context, does "4 semester units" refer to 4 credit hours or 4 graduate courses?

Comment: Did you try emailing the department?

Comment: Almost certainly the former, but only they can give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Semester units" are up to the definition of the school. Some people call a "unit" one course; some people call a "unit" a fraction of a course.

For example, just among the US schools that I have been affiliated with (or visited for an extended period of time):

> Yale: 1 semester course = 1 unit
>
> Harvard: 1 semester course = 1/2 unit
>
> Princeton: 1 semester course = 1 unit
>
> MIT: 1 semester course = 9 or 12 units
>
> UConn: 1 semester course = 3 or 4 "credit hours"

So you *definitely* need to consult the *individual school catalog* to see what system they're using.